# Unable to add more than one .vsix extensions to my Windows 10 app

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have a Windows phone 8 app, which I am porting to Windows 10.The app uses two **.vsix** extensions.

1. **XXXX Universal Windows SDK**
2. **XXXX Universal Windows Helper SDK**

These are the two .vsix extensions being used by the app. The **XXXX** is the company name. 
The issue which I am facing is, I am unable to add both these .vsix extensions to my sample in Windows 10.
I add extension **1**(XXXX Universal Windows SDK) to my app. The extension gets added & I can see all the symbols in this extension via VS Object Browser. Then I add extension **2**(XXXX Universal Windows Helper SDK) to app,  the symbols exported by extension **2** overwrites symbols exported by extension **1** & VS complains about inability to find any symbols exported by extension **1**
The vice-versa i.e if I install extension **2** followed by extension **1**, VS can only see symbols from **1** & complains about symbols from **2**
This used to work in VS-2013 & on Windows phone 8. The corresponding **.vsix** were then named ***XXXX Windows Phone 8 SDK*** & ***XXXX Windows Phone 8 Helper SDK*** respectively. 
Is this a new behavior in Windows 10? Does **VS2015** not allow more than one **.vsix** of the same name (**XXXX** in the two extension's name above are the same. It is our company name) ?

Comment: I suggest you contact company XXX for support.

Comment: Hi @IgorKulman, Thanks for the response. Actually, I work for company XXXX. Our company provides audio discovery & recommendation services. We have our own SDK written in native C/C++. We create .dll's of our SDK & package them as .vsix extensions. We create samples on all mobile platforms, demonstrating the use cases for our SDK's. Following this process, I am trying to create sample on Windows-10 (UWP) platform & hitting this issue.